# is there a way to store a file from url into s3's specific folder, not just into the root?

Tags: image, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

found a way to upload a file from an url into s3 bucket but is there a way to direct it into a specific folder or create a folder?

I get it working to store into s3's root by using the code below

```
def save_image_s3(self, img_url, img_name):
    """Saves the image in img_url into S3 with the name img_name"""
    conn = boto.connect_s3(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = img_name
    fp = StringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(img_url).read())
    k.set_contents_from_file(fp)
    return img_name
```

Again, this does save it into my bucket's root directory but I am not sure how I can direct it to save into an existing folder or make a new folder if folder does not exist

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, you can set `k.key` to the full "path" in the bucket to your object.
For example:

```
k.key = 'photos/%s' % img_name
```

This will save it to what you would consider a "folder" named `photos`.  There is no need for the folder itself to be created first, since S3 folders do not actually exist but are implied by the appearance of one or more `/` appearing within object keys.  Do not add `/` at the beginning.